# How to extract data from an API get request in react with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-chartjs-2

I'm Working with react on an API that returns an array[2] and inside has another Array [11] that inside have 11 arrays with the data i need and some that I don't need to fetch. I'm using axios to make the get request and I'm able to print the data with console.log and i geI a 200, but I need to extract the values of time and mean and pass that data to a chart, can someone help me I'm a bit stuck

I try to use a map method but I it didn't work.

this is the code i try to use:
```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

```
  const URLAPI = 'apiurl'
  try {
  const response = await axios.get(URLAPI);
  const data = response.data.data[2][0].map(item => item.mean);
  setChartData(data);
  } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  }
  };

  return (
  <div>
  <h1>Line Chart</h1>
  <Line
    data={{
      labels: Array.from(Array(chartData.length).keys()), // Use index as 
  labels
      datasets: [
        {
          data: chartData,
          label: 'Mean Values',
          borderColor: 'blue',
          fill: false,
         },
       ],
     }}
     />
    </div>
  );
  }

  export default LineChartComponent;
```

Comment: could you please share some code which you have tried ?

Comment: i paste the last try i did yesterday :/ hope it helps , sorry i'm new to coding =)

Answer (score 0):

I added some modifications to your code.
Use the Array.prototype.flat() method to flatten the nested array it will be easier to access the inner arrays. Then, you can use the map() method to extract the time and mean values from each inner array.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

const LineChartComponent = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(URLAPI);
        const nestedArray = response.data.data[2][0];
        const flattenedArray = nestedArray.flat(); // Flatten the nested array
        const data = flattenedArray.map(item => ({
          time: item.time,
          mean: item.mean
        }));
        setChartData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array to run the effect only once

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Line Chart</h1>
      <Line
        data={{
          labels: chartData.map(item => item.time), // Use time values as labels
          datasets: [
            {
              data: chartData.map(item => item.mean), // Use mean values as data
              label: 'Mean Values',
              borderColor: 'blue',
              fill: false,
            },
          ],
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default LineChartComponent;
```